# How to train neural network to say whether a given input belongs to the samples we have in dataset or not?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Suppose I have n samples with m features and a binary output (say 0 or 1). How do I create a neural network model which says whether a given input(to be predicted sample) is present in the samples(dataset) we have or not ?

Comment: Are you trying to do one-class classification? Or are you trying to predict the binary output?

Comment: From how I understand this question, it does not involve any kind of learning?

Comment: It's just how to build a network which can tell whether a newly given input sample is present in our dataset or not
Suppose you have a dataset of numbers from 1-100 now i want to build a network such that when it is given a input say '56' it should say whether it is present in the sample on which it is trained or not

Comment: Why train at all, why not just look in the samples to see if the given input is already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to do this is basically [the Barber paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox).

One way to think of this problem is as a binary classification task: all points that are in your data set are class 0 and all points *outside* of your data set are class 1. But this immediately encounters a rather large conceptual problem: how do you find any examples of class 1? If you put such an example in your data set, then it's transformed into class 0. But if the sample is *not* in your data set, you can't train the model to recognize it -- because it's not in your data set.

---

The easiest way to determine if a feature vector is in your data set is to just use subtraction; ignoring floating point error, any points with a difference of 0 are in your data set.

Comment: "The easiest way to determine if a feature vector is in your data set is to just use subtraction; ignoring floating point error, any points with a difference of 0 are in your data set."-
Can you elaborate it more clearly

Comment: Your data set is some vectors $x_i$ and you want to know if $y$ is in that set. For each $x_i$, compute $x_i - y$. If $0 \le |x_i - y| < 2.2 \times 10^{-16}$, then you know that $y$ is in your data set.

Comment: I think i need to rewrite the question.
It's about can we build a neural network which can say whether a given input is present in our dataset already or not we are not talking about 'y' It's just whether a newly taken input which isn't in our dataset and to know whether that input already exists in our dataset or not

Comment: @KaushikSB In Sycorax's comment, $y$ *is* the "newly taken input" you're referring to (maybe you interpreted it as a target output, since $y$ sometimes means that?). If you *really* want a neural net, you can easily build one by hand that does exactly what Sycorax suggested; no learning needed. But there wouldn't be much point to this.

Comment: Can you put up the code ?

Comment: `[d(x,y) < 2.2e-16 for x in X]`